# XenCenter can't connect to XCP server after restart

Tags: xenserver, xen

After restarting a XCP 1.6.10 host machine, XenCenter 6.1 is no longer able to connect to it. The failure message is always *"Server failure: Unauthorized"*. Using `ssh` with the exact same root credentials works fine.

I can't seem to find any log on the box that would help me to diagnose this issue, is there any place where connection attempts to `openwsmand` are logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across the same phenomenon, here's what I found out (spoiler: I'm stupid):

Of course, what should have immediately raised an alarm was the fact that I wrote `openwsmand` when the `xapi` process is actually responsible for handling connection attempts from XenCenter and the likes. What happened here was that I just did a simple `netstat -plant` and noticed that `openwsmand` was listening at port 443, which I knew was the port that XenCenter tried to connect to, so I assumed this was the right process.

But of course, XenCenter can't connect to `openwsmand` because this is a tool of the OpenManage Suite by Dell. I suppose that when I first installed OpenManage, `openwsmand` tried to bind to port 443, but this was already in use by `xapi`, so it gave up and I was still able to connect.

When I restarted the machine, however, the `openwsmand` service was started before `xapi`, so it occupied port 443, leaving me with no possibility to connect using XenCenter.

A simple

```
$ service openwsmand stop
$ xe-toolstack-restart
$ service openwsmand start
```

fixed the problem. Currently running VMs won't be affected by this operation.